# Google Colab: edit two lines at the same time

Tags: google-colaboratory

In my local jupyter-notebook i can edit mutliple lines of code at the same time: simply press ctrl + click at the respective lines. In google Colab that does not seem to work. Is this feature available somehow?

I work with Firefox on a Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

It's available. Instead of Ctrl + Click, please use

- Alt + Click for Windows
- Option + Click for MacOS

To select all occurrences of the current selection, please use

- Ctrl + Shift + L for Windows
- Command + Shift + L for MacOS

Comment: Awesome crl+shiftt+L works for linux/ubuntu16.04 as well. However alt+click does not work for my ubuntu. Do you know that one for ubuntu as well?

Comment: On Mac OS you can also select multiple lines using `Option + Shift + Click` and then dragging to select the lines you want.

Comment: Ctrl + Shift + L doesn't seem to work on my Pixelbook. The cell highlights matching occurrences of the selection in the same cell but I can't seem to find out how to include them into the selection in a single keystroke.

Alt + Click does work, but it's a lot of effort to include all matching occurrences if there are a lot of them.

Comment: Update: Ctrl + Shift +L works but _only if_ nothing is selected at the time of pressing those keys.

Comment: On another side-note: CTRL+D expands the selection to all occurrences of the selection.

Answer (score 9):

(In Linux - Chromium, at least)

I managed to do block select but only on contiguous lines, not multi-cursor unfortunately.

Shift+Alt + Up/Down to select multiple lines.
Now you can release Alt and use Left/Right to move to the sides. Whatever you do now will affect the whole block.

[image]

And, if you select one or more lines with Shift (doesn't need to be the whole content, this affects all the lines with cursor), and then release Shift and press Alt+Up/Down, you will move those lines altogether up/down

[image]

**By Rainer Glüge:** On Linux+Firefox:

- Block-Select: Ctrl+Shift+Alt+Cursor Keys.
- Multi-Cursor: Alt+Click
- Multi-Select: Select one occurence, then Ctrl+Shift+L

Comment: That doesn't seem to work on my Pixelbook (Google Chromebook).

Comment: On Linux+Firefox: 
Block-Select: Ctrl+Shift+Alt+Cursor Keys. 
Multi-Cursor: Alt+Click
Multi-Select: Select one occurence, then Ctrl+Shift+L

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way:

You can just **press `Shift`+`Ctrl`+`Up/Down` keys**.
(Tried with Ubuntu + Google Chrome).

`Shift`+`Alt` also works, but I find `Shift`+`Ctrl` easier.