# Is there a shortcut for selecting current word when editing a cell in jupyter notebook?

Tags: visual-studio, jupyter-notebook

I know there is the shortcut `ctrl + w` in visual studio for selecting current word.
Is there a shortcut or an extension for jupyter notebook which does the same?

Answer (score 3):

Hah! I found the answer shortly after putting a bounty out. On Chromebook (in Colab) it's CTRL+D. Presumably this works in Jupyter and on Windows also. On Mac it may be CMD+D, but I haven't tried.

The winning tip came from two other answers on keyboard shortcuts in Jupyter:

- [Atom/Sublime like Multiple selections in Jupyter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41553806/atom-sublime-like-multiple-selections-in-jupyter)
- [Google Colab: edit two lines at the same time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60053748/google-colab-edit-two-lines-at-the-same-time) (block editing)

Comment: on mac cmd+d will delete the line!

Comment: It won't work in Jupyter as in Colab, as `CTRL+D` (Windows & Linux) and `CMD+D` (Mac) is a shortcut for deleting the current line.
I am not sure if there is a similar command in Jupyter, but the closest approach I know is `ESC+F` which opens "find & replace" so you can replace all the word's repetitions at once.

Comment: I'm on Ubuntu linux, and until today, `control`+`d` deleted the current line. Now it selects the current word instead, and ***no*** combination of modifiers with `d` seems to delete a single line. Not too please.